# Scalar becoming matrix without asking R

Tags: r, matrix, scalar

I'm writing a chi-sq stat test in R and my scalar chisq is being converted to a matrix and I can't figure out why.

The variables used here include

k is a scalar

f is a kxk matrix

n is the number of data points being evaluated

chisq is meant to be a scalar but becomes a matrix each time I run this code.

Any help would be appreciated

```
for(i in 1:k){
    for(j in 1:k){
        chisq<-chisq+(f[i,j]-(n/(k^2)))^2
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `as.numeric`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to calculate a $\chi^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reproducible chunk of code:

```
chisq=0
k=3
f=matrix(runif(k*k),k,k)
n=3
for(i in 1:k){
    for(j in 1:k){
        chisq<-chisq+(f[i,j]-(n/(k^2)))^2
    }
}
```

And `chisq` comes out as a scalar. If I start with `chisq` as a matrix, I get a matrix out:

```
 chisq = matrix(0,1,1)
```

So, I suspect you are doing the latter, despite what you say. Reproducible examples are there for you as well as us.